# Word wrap of LyX

Tags: word-wrap, lyx

Any one knows which part of the source code of LyX is related to word wrapping of CJK languages?
Seems this [bug/defect](http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/4635) has been identified for over 5 years but still left unclosed.
Wondering if I can fix it myself but get stuck in locating the source file of word wrapping...

Comment: Please write to lyx-devel@lists.lyx.org. It would be nice to solve this issue.

Comment: Well...I tried that but no one replied me...

Comment: Richard Heck replied the same day you sent the email. He replied both to you and to the list. Maybe it went to your spam folder? You can see his response here: http://www.mail-archive.com/lyx-devel@lists.lyx.org/msg177765.html

Comment: Aha, Yes I got it. Sorry for not replying. But there is no RowMetrics.cpp actually. However I found ParagraphMetrics.cpp/h which seems to defines the RowList into which a paragraph is broken, but still didn't figure out how it works. So I sent email to Younes (younes.a@free.fr) and Jürgen (jug@lyx.org), who are the authors of that ParagraphMetrics.cpp, but got no reply.

Comment: @scottkosty btw I sent to Jürgen Spitzmüller yesterday because I found his name on the [ticket](http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/4635). He replied very soon, but suggest me to ask LyX Developers list......

Comment: Yes, all of the people you mentioned (Younes only occasionally) are on the list. If you have a follow-up question or are not satisfied with a response, just bump the email again.

Comment: Haha~sounds good. Let me try that:)